What is function of בו?
A grammar question

הן עבדי אתמך בו בחירי רצתה נפשי נתתי רוחי עליו משפט לגוים יוציא
Behold my servant, whom I uphold; mine elect, in whom my soul delighteth; I have put my spirit upon him: he shall bring forth judgment to the Gentiles
(Isaiah 42:1)


It's a preposition + pronominal 3rd person masculine singular suffix, probably best literally translated as "in him".
In the translation you provided, it's the equivalent of "whom": Behold my servant, whom I uphold.
